# JavaScript Performance switch (Integer) vs switch (String)

Tags: javascript, performance, enums, integer, switch-statement

I'm coming from C# and there it's a huge different between 
A:

```
var stringVal = "1";
switch (stringVal)
{
    case "0" :
    break;
    case "1" :
    break;
}
```

and 
 B:

```
var intVal = 1;
switch (intVal)
{
    case 0 :
    break;
    case 1 :
    break;
}
```

B is much faster in C# (cause the String-Switch will converted to if-else-structure from the compiler).

Is it in JavaScript similar? (Of course there is just the number-type in JS) 
And - for readability - if i want to use it with some enum-"equivalent" in JS (like described here http://stijndewitt.com/2014/01/26/enums-in-javascript/), is there a anyway performance-improvement when using

```
var caseEnum = {
    firstCase : 0,
    secCase : 1
}

var enumVal = caseEnum.secCase ;
switch (enumVal )
{
    case caseEnum.firstCase :
    break;
    case caseEnum.secCase :
    break;
}
```

?

(I know that i could do it with object literals, but the switch-statement with integer is more naturally for me)

Comment: "Is it in JavaScript similar?" Depends on the interpreter implementation.

Comment: It's *probably* faster to use integers, but the JIT is a mysterious thing. When in doubt, profile.

Answer (score 3):

I did a little incredible ugly Test on my own 
( `look at:`https://jsfiddle.net/PutziSan/kzdwt8u2 )

and run the code on different browsers (results below), (all the browsers was updated on the latest version today - 03.01.2016)

by the way another hint, that edge and IE is just ridiculous.

 The results are realy interesting, i  guess.
(I know this sort of "tests" are not that accurate, but i think they can give a hint)

It seems, that switch with Integer is noticed from the compilers, but it has not that great impact.

chrome:
[image: chrome]

firefox:
[image: firefox]

edge:
[image: edge]

IE:
[image: IE]

Comment: Really helpful and interesting time comparison, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it in JavaScript similar? (Of course there is just the number-type in JS)

In javascript the expression can be almost anything, its not like in `C` where the type is verified during compilation, here its being calculated during "runtime"

That's the main difference.

A very detailed explanation is in the [MDN - Switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

> ... expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression
>    (**using strict comparison, ===**)

---

> ... is there a anyway performance-improvement

It depends on your browser and its JS engine.

Comment: yes, but is there also the performance-gain when I use switch with Integer in javascript? So does it make sense to do it with Integer?

Comment: The fastest way is none of them. Hash is much faster then them all.|
http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/is-hash-faster-than-switch-in-javascript/